# IE8 JQuery object doesn't support this property or method line 4 character 6105

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've testing my page in IE8 with JQuery, but the following error is ocurring, the IE doesn't recognizing JQuery, displaying the following message:

The Object doesn't support this property or method line 4 character 6105.

Below my HTML code:

```
<head>
        <title><?php echo "SIBE - Sistema de Informação Bio Extratus" ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />  

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fwsibe/assets/css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fwsibe/assets/css/quickmenu2.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.custom.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/plugins/datepicker/datetimepicker.css" />-->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fwsibe/assets/jquery/css/demos.css" />-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fwsibe/assets/jquery/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript" >
            function tamanho() {
                document.principal.largura.value = screen.width;
                document.principal.altura.value = screen.height;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
```

Jquery Code:

```
/**
 * Script JQuery principal que inicializa a execução de outros scripts
 */

/**
 * 
 * @type String dirScriptsEvento diretório padrão com o caminho dos scripts que gerenciam eventos dos diversos componetes
 * @type Array arrayScripts contém o caminho de cada script a ser executado
 */
var dirJquery = "/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/";
var dirJqueryPlugins = dirJquery + "plugins/";
var dirScriptsEvento = dirJquery + "scripts/eventos/";
var dirJqueryUi = dirJquery + "lib/jquery-ui/";
var arrayScripts = new Array(
        dirJqueryPlugins + "datepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery-ajax_singleton-0.0.3.min.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Menu.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Dialog.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Button.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Template.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Select.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "InputDate.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery.maskedinput.min.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery.form.min.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"
        );


$(function() {

    //Carrega os scripts JQuery
    loadScripts();

});
/**
 * Recarrega os scripts de evento jQuery sempre que um determinado evento acontece
 */
function loadScripts() {

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayScripts.length; i++) {
        jQuery.getScript(arrayScripts[i]);
    }

}
```

The error occurs on `jquery.min.js`, in the following line:

```
x.ready.promise=function(t){
return n ||(n=x.Deferred(), "complete"===o.readyState?setTimeout(x.ready):...
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, can't help you. the error is happening somewhere in jquery, but you've shown none of your own code which could possibly be triggering it. Note that your html is invalid. your final script is not closed, so the `<style>` tag is actually being treated as javascript code.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  You need to use the 1.x series for IE 8.

Comment: I edited the html code above, I insert the code according to my schedule, as was previously under the console firefox. But remembering that the problem is in IE8.

Comment: I've using the version jquery-2.0.3.min. I didn't know which for IE8 the version should bd 1.X. You know which latest version can be used?

Comment: I changed the version of my JQuery for 1.10 and the problem was solved. Thanks!

Comment: I'm being censored? If I have a question and can not find the answer I can not post? See how many threads I created and got answers that solved my problems and make sure other people. But my reputation is always diminished. I do not think the Stack Overflow democratic, it seems that people here do not want others to grow, it seems that fighting for others may not have reputation to answer questions, answers, solutions ... I'm happy for Stack Overflow enable me to find help but get upset by people here give a bad reputation to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version of jQuery is too new. The 2.x branch has dropped support for older versions of IE in favor of a smaller file size. The 1.x branch is still being updated, however, and you can continue to use that if you require support for IE8 and below.

See the [jQuery 2.0 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) for details on this change to the library.